# I do not find a server in sql 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, azure, nopcommerce

I have a free trial of Azure for a month. I want to install nopCommerce site to try out using Azure for hosting.

I have Commerce installed locally on my PC with a SQL Server compact.

In Azure this shall be installed with an usual SQL database. However - I am not allowed to this by the system.

I have tried for two days now to install a server in my PC based on SQL Server 2008 R2. The system does not find a server and I cannot find out how to install a server that the SQL management system finds.

I am stuck - and do not know what to do. I have tried to reinstall SQL Server 2008 R2 after uninstalling the old one, with no luck.

As far as this condition lives, I cannot find out if Azure is my future solution for hosting my website.

I would really appreciate any help the community can provide me. Thank you.

Comment: If you have already installed a different version of SQL Server (compact) then you may have to write down the name of the server in SQL Server Management Studio. What did you name the full version of SQL Server when you installed it?

Comment: I have tried to find the name of the server, but with no luck. I have looked into SQL server Management but cannot find it. May be I look at wrong places. Can you tell me where to look ? Thanks.